Possible to have two different kinds of objects in a SwiftUI selectable List?
in a book club app I'm trying to write, I have a NavigationSplitView which displays a list of readers in a selectable List that gives the user access to each reader's comments on a given book. At the top of the list is a button "Book" that takes the user back to the book's main page:
struct ProjectView: View
{
    @State private var readers: [Reader]
    @State private var selectedReader: Reader?
    
    init(readers: [Reader])
    {
        self.readers = readers
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationSplitView
        {
                List(selection: self.$selectedReader)
                {
                    Button("Book")
                    {
                        self.selectedReader = nil
                    }
                    
                    Divider()
                                        
                    ForEach (self.readers, id: \.self)
                    {
                        reader in Text(reader.name)
                    }
                }
        }
        detail:
        {
            if let selectedReader = self.selectedReader
            {
                ReaderView(reader: selectedReader)
            }
            else
            {
                BookView()
            }
        }
        #if os(macOS)
        .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 180, ideal: 200)
        #endif
        .navigationTitle(self.project.name)
    }
}

I'm trying to make it so that "Book" will select / highlight just as the reader names in the reader list do, you can see what I mean in this video:
https://youtube.com/shorts/__IA890FxG0?feature=share
Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Or is it even possible?

Note, you should not initialise self.readers = readers, it should be
_readers = State(initialValue: readers), or use let readers: [Reader].
If you need to change readers then use a @Binding.
Also, you should not use ForEach (self.readers, id: \.self),
make the struct Reader Identifiable.
How do you declare selectedReader? Note,  Above the list of readers is a home button "Book" ...
no, the button is at the top of the list, not above it.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks for the tips. Forgot to add in the declaration for selectedReader, changed it.

You should use a ReaderOrBook?, since the selection can be either a reader, or "Book", or nothing is selected at all (nil).
enum ReaderOrBook: Hashable {
    case book
    case reader(Reader)
    
    // convenient property to convert a ReaderOrBook to a Reader 
    var asReader: Reader? {
        if case let .reader(r) = self {
            return r
        }
        return nil
    }
}

Then you just need to tag the list rows appropriately.
struct ProjectView: View {
    // this should not be a @State since you want callers to pass in an array of readers
    // if you want to mutate this in ProjectView, make it a @Binding instead
    let readers: [Reader]
    @State private var selectedReaderOrBook: ReaderOrBook?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: self.$selectedReaderOrBook) {
                Text("Book").tag(ReaderOrBook.book)
                
                Divider()
                
                ForEach (self.readers, id: \.self) { reader in
                    Text(reader.name)
                        .tag(ReaderOrBook.reader(reader))
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            // ...
        }
    }
}


Wow that is such a great solution, I just implemented it and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!
